# How to have one single loop tailing a collection and serving all of the WebSocketHandlers in Tornado?

Tags: python, tornado, tornado-motor

The following code runs a single `while True` loop and serves all of the listeners with the same data. It works as I intended it to work but I think it is ugly. Is there a better way to achieve this?

In reality I will tail MongoDB oplog, parse the output and serve only interested listeners. In that case `listeners` would be a dict with key being ObjectID for example and value an array of WebSocketHandlers. Does this sound like a good idea?

```
class TestHandler(WebSocketHandler):
    running = False
    listeners = []

    @gen.coroutine
    def open(self):
        TestHandler.listeners.append(self)
        if not TestHandler.running:
            TestHandler.start_stream()

    def on_close(self):
        TestHandler.listeners.remove(self)

    @staticmethod
    @gen.coroutine
    def start_stream():
        # this will in reality tail mongodb oplog and serve changes
        # but this is nice enough to demonstrate the problem
        TestHandler.running = True
        i = 0
        while True:
            for socket in TestHandler.listeners:
                socket.write_message(str(i))
            i += 1
            loop = IOLoop.instance()
            yield gen.Task(loop.add_timeout, time.time() + 1)
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. I assume you've studied the [tailable cursors example in Motor's docs](http://motor.readthedocs.org/en/stable/examples/tailable-cursors.html)?

Comment: I did but it doesn't say anything about how the function is invoked.
Is there a way to start function at application start? That way I lose if not running construct which bothers me a lot.

Comment: To start a function at application start, **call** it from your main application file! It doesn't need to be a class method either, just a regular function will do. You're overthinking this. =)

Comment: I got confused, because this does not work:
`tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start();
TestHandler.start_stream()`
You need to call function before you start the instance loop, which is weird if you ask me because I was certain if I call `start_stream` before I start IOLoop it would loop forever and IOLoop would never start. I guess I need a better understanding of IOLoop and how code executes in async world.

Comment: If you call a coroutine it returns a Future and runs in the background, like launching a thread. It's only when you yield the Future that you wait for the coroutine to finish (you "join" it). So in your case you can easily launch the tailing coroutine, then continue in your main code.